# How do I access SharePoint from HTML 5 page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, web-part

I am working on a web application using HTML 5. In this web application I need to post and get information from the Content Database in SharePoint Server 2013.

I tried using REST API method but I can't find the proper way to do it.

Can anyone guide or give some example on how to do this.

Comment: What do you need exactly? Access to list items? what?

Comment: Guessing on other's question is not the right thing to do when editing, IMHO. It's the poster's responsibility to make the question the clearest as possible. "Getting information from the content database" still doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @Thanigai give us an example of what you have tried, so we can tell you if you messed up the syntax or not.